# Bash string parameter is printed with unnecessary apostrophes

Tags: string, bash, docker

I'm writing a BASH script on ubuntu 18 OS.
I'm doing manipulation on a string (append, cut)
and after that, I want to use it as a parameter for a docker command.
the problem is that it returns with apostrophes and I need only the value without those.

```
if [[ "${TESTIM_LABEL}" =~ "," ]]; then
    IFS=','
    read -a strarr <<< "$TESTIM_LABEL"
    LABELS=""
    prefix=" --label "
    for val in "${strarr[@]}";
    do
      LABELS+=${prefix}${val}
      echo "$LABELS"

    done
        printf "$LABELS"
  else
      printf "im outside the IF"
      LABELS="--label ${TESTIM_LABEL}"
fi
```

on this IF statement when the condition is true and I'm inside the IF then the value of LABELS variable printed **without** apostrophes
but
when I use this param later as part of a longer command it being inserted **with apostrophes**

example:

```
    RESULT=$(docker run --rm -e rpLaunch="${RP_LAUNCH_NAME}" -e rpTeam="${RP_TEAM}" -e rpUuid="${rp_uuid}" -e rpBranchNameTag="${BRANCH_NAME}" -e rpDescription="${RP_DESCRIPTION}" -v $2:/opt/testim-runner ${TESTIM_DOCKER} \
  --token ${TESTIM_TOKEN} \
  --project "${TESTIM_PROJECT}" \
  ${LABELS}
```

output will be (after inserting to the IF "xxx,yyy"):

```
docker run --rm -e rpLaunch=master/testim/@arion_ab_testing -e rpTeam=SocialArion -e rpUuid= -e rpBranchNameTag=master -e rpDescription=http://jenkins-prod-search.internalk.com/job/ui-pull-request/3127/ -v /home/centos/jenkins/workspace/ui-pull-request:/opt/testim-runner testim/docker-cli --token Dt9kFOtOhNcMum2gZjvnapOpGyq8vgreEnZOJF2nR9SeCJaRGE --project bJFghGy6Jo9yvtOO3ZiO ' --label xxx --label yyy'
```

and those apostrophes around **' --label xxx --label yyy'**  need to be removed.

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where the error is coming from, but `LABELS` itself should also be an array: e.g., `LABELS=(--label xxx --label yyy)` and `RESULT=$(docker ... "${LABELS[@]}")`.

Comment: Did you actually quote the parameter expansion, i.e., `RESULT=$(docker ... "$LABELS")`? That would be consistent with the `-x` option producing the output you show.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://tio.run/##ZVJdb4IwFH3nV9w0JD5MYrLHKckUWeZUMIBPzpgKZXQKJaUsGMP@uitfm7q@cDnnntN7brrHWXS5eKbrzZa7xXhiLvSiKPqn00lRaAibDSD1fE2XCPRvQH0E2@0QREQSBeSZvbh6r9@ra05wABqGTHDMOYxGI2ly7YHqtrp0ddT8pZyEtNARaNoR78kRGjhkHL7wEWhSDdI4bp63JRrWdMDqT2f2oKvnxqhUz1JWtizxIyb1TRNSWmlCWvpfgwSOGbkR0xhYLjIakCq0zItubtZRN/f9upSQKkrtETD/QDjwPJEheQwaAZ4ucJ74kS7DOSspWVvG684aL02555r3CI5b1jPHyw5e5zSoYJ7ucll28IRj6WbhmHj4o@InzvjecUoyn9NUUJa0xlPTNZzZypvZVtX0Berj04ClYiBIJmisyYkTOfhvsqltzE2nhHe5Ak0T7ECSP9Kz56bVcSlnn8QXV49o5dhvpuHJe6oO9dysr7xcfgA

Comment: You don't need `if`/`else` here, you can loop over the comma-separated parts of `$TESTIM_LABEL` with `IFS=, read -ra strarr <<< "$TESTIM_LABEL"; for val in "${strarr[@]}"; do labels+=('--label' "$val"); done` and then use `"${labels[@]}"`.

Comment: That doesn't explain where the quotes come from, though, and I don't believe the code you show reproduces that behaviour.

Comment: chepner - i did try to quote the parameter expansion as you suggested. it didn't helped :\

Comment: Benjamin W. you suggestion to replace the if solved the issue for me. thank you very much!!

Comment: I'd want to see what's actually in the `$TESTIM_LABEL` variable and how it's being parsed into the array; could you ... after populating the `strarr` array, add `typeset -p TESTIM_LABEL strarr`, then update the question with the output

Comment: If I understand right, the original problem was due to setting `IFS=','`, and never setting `IFS` back to normal. As a result, `${LABELS}` doesn't get split on spaces (but on commas, which it doesn't have any of), so it's passed as a single argument (spaces and all), so `set -x` puts single-quotes around it to indicate that the spaces in it are part of the argument (note: `set -x` prints something *equivalent* to what's being executed).

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment] ... I'm thinking this may come down to a (simple) issue of how the `TESTIM_LABEL` variable is being populated. [**NOTE**: OP has yet to show us how said variable is being populated.]

One simple example, using OP's current code for demonstration purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -p "enter TESTIM_LABEL: " TESTIM_LABEL      # added to OP's code; have user enter value @ prompt;
                                                 # the rest is cut-n-pasted from the question ...

if [[ "${TESTIM_LABEL}" =~ "," ]]; then 
    IFS=','
    read -a strarr <<< "$TESTIM_LABEL"
    LABELS=""
    prefix=" --label "
    for val in "${strarr[@]}";
    do
      LABELS+=${prefix}${val}
      echo "$LABELS"

    done
        printf "$LABELS"
  else
      printf "im outside the IF"
      LABELS="--label ${TESTIM_LABEL}"
fi
```

A couple sample runs where we do (not) quote the input:

```
$ testim.bash
enter TESTIM_LABEL: 'xxx,yyy'
 --label 'xxx
 --label 'xxx --label yyy'
 --label 'xxx --label yyy'              # unwanted quotes

$ testim.bash
enter TESTIM_LABEL: xxx,yyy
 --label xxx
 --label xxx --label yyy
 --label xxx --label yyy                # no quotes
```

Granted, there may be another explanation but it would help if OP provides more details on how the `TESTIM_LABEL` variable is being set.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove them like so:

```
test="'test'"

#with
$ echo "$test"
'test'

#without
$ echo "${test//\'}"
test
```